# Using tabindex between forms with typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to implement tabbing between my input fields by using typescript. I have the following code...

index.html

```
   <ion-fab bottom right fab-size=60px>
          <button ion-fab icon-only class="btn-nav" id="down" >
            <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <button ion-fab icon-only class="btn-nav" id="up" >
            <ion-icon name="arrow-up" ></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-fab>

 <form [formGroup]="itemForm" (submit)="addItem()" novalidate>
    <ion-row class="questions">
      <ion-col col-sm-2 col-md-8>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked class="ques-title">General Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="gen_name" class="input-field" type="text" tabindex="1" 
        [class.invalid]="!itemForm.controls.gen_name.valid && itemForm.controls.gen_name.dirty">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" 
      *ngIf="!itemForm.controls.gen_name.valid && itemForm.controls.gen_name.dirty">
      <p>
        Problem with the general name. No Special characters 
      </p>
    </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
.
.
.
</form>
```

index.ts

```
 public pos: number = 0;
  public navUp: any = document.getElementById('up');
  public navDown: any = document.getElementById('down');


  setFocus () {
    document.querySelector('input[tabindex="' + this.pos +'"]').focus();
  }

  navUp.onclick () {
    this.pos = this.pos-1;
    this.setFocus();
  }

  navDown.onclick () {
    this.pos = this.pos+1;
    this.setFocus();
  }
```

But when I compile it, it shows me the following error

- Typescript Error Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'.
- Typescript Error Duplicate identifier 'navUp'.
- Typescript Error Duplicate function implementation.
- Typescript Error Duplicate identifier 'navDown'.
- Typescript Error ';' expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with ionic, but I know a couple of things about TypeScript that might help.

Example code:

```
class Example {
    public pos: number = 0;

    constructor() {
        var navUp = document.getElementById('up');
        var navDown = document.getElementById('down');

        navUp.onclick = () => {
            this.pos = this.pos - 1;
            this.setFocus();
        }

        navDown.onclick = () => {
            this.pos = this.pos + 1;
            this.setFocus();
        }
    }

    setFocus() {
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('input[tabindex="' + this.pos + '"]')).focus();
    }
}
```

1. Not all elements have a `focus` method - but if you give TypeScript a little type assertion by saying "I know that the string `'input[...` will always give me an `HTMLInputElement` - it will be happy.
2. I have fixed the click handlers so they compile, but please read the [MDN guidelines on adding click handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) as it recommends `addEventListener`.